# RoR + Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want use jQuery in my project. I know the javascript_include_tag calls the jQuery plugins, but the `<script type="text/javascript">` tag how does it work in ruby?

Example

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.potato.menu.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#menu1').ptMenu();
        });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This is not working in RoR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse your script tags, like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.potato.menu.js' %>
```

jQuery needs to be loaded before anything that *depends* on jQuery tries to run, e.g. plugins.

Also consider upgrading if you're just getting started.  If the plugin you're using support it, the latest (as of the time of this answer) is [1.4.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/).

Answer (score 2):

Put the

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js' %>
```

before any jquery plugins. (i.e. the potato thing.)

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work?
if the first file in the order needs jQuery in order to work (usually does) then you should load it only after jquery loads, meaning change the order of the files.

another thing, check with firebug if the files are loading correctly and there's no 404 error or something like that