# JQuery events cannot be called with type="text/javascript"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

For some reason, the following code will work:

The following code does not work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#login_password').click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  });
</script>
```

But it does when I do not specify the script type like so:

```
<script>
  ...
</script>
```

Why do I need to leave the script type unspecified for event calls on elements?

Even more oddly, the following will work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_username").focus();
  });
</script>
```

I am using JQuery 1.6.1 on Rails 3.0.9.  The gem jquery-rails 1.0.12 is installed and bundled.

In my application.html.erb I call:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js', 'jquery.min.js', 'jquery.rails.js' %>
```

Where jquery.rails.js is the unobtrusive scripting adapter https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the first snippet placed in your `<head>` tag? I'll bet the issue is trying to execute a script on the DOM before the DOM is ready - which explains why the third snippet works fine.

Comment: This was essentially the issue.
After seeing [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501385/ror-jquery-not-working/3501401#3501401), I changed the order of my script requests so that I now have 

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min.js', 'jquery.rails.js', 'application.js' %>

This ensures that the JQuery library is loaded before I start to make calls on it.

Comment: In case you'd like to give credit, I added my response as an answer with a bit more detail :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to execute a script on the DOM before the DOM is ready, which explains why the third snippet works fine.

If your scripts are loaded before the elements you're working with (e.g. including the scripts in the `<head>` tag), be sure to wrap them like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // manipulate DOM here
});

// or

jQuery(function($) {
    // manipulate DOM here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your first example with $(document).ready like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#login_password').click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: He wouldn't be able to click it if it wasn't in the DOM ;)

Answer (score 1):

See the comment from Kevin, he is right. The fact that is worked without specifying the type attribute is just timing luck or some browser-specific fluke.